# Changing width of autocomplete field and dropdown make them go in two different directions

Tags: jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, google-api

I'm using Google's auto complete API. I'm also using a JQuery which animates the autocomplete field making it wider. However, the dropdown is not being positioned correctly when i have float right on the autocomplete field.

To test this type a letter then move the focus away from the field, then focus on the field again, you will see that the field and the dropdown get wider, but in 2 different directions.

(Note: it works with float:left, but I want to use float right for this)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <title>Place Autocomplete Form</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>

        function initialize() {

          autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')));

          $('#autocomplete').focus(function() {

            $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
            $(this).animate({ width: 315 }, 'slow');
            $('.pac-container').animate({ width: 315 }, 'slow');

        }).blur(function() {

            var w = 150;
            $(this).animate({ width: w }, 'slow');
            $('.pac-container').animate({ width: w }, 'slow');

        });

        }

    </script>

    <style>

      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        margin-right:300px;
        right: 0px;
        width: 150px;
        float:right;
      }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body onload="initialize()">

    <div id="locationField">

      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" 
      onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```